# Generate wsp file using TFS Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package, tfs

I have a SP 2013 project created using VS 2012 solution.Its added into TFS.
Now i have to give it to customer, such that whenever there is a change they  will take a build from TSF server and deploy and genrate the wsp.Later,this wsp would be deployed on staging and prod. environment.
But I am stuck with how to generate a wsp from TFS server.
Can someone help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure a build server for your TFS, and set up your SharePoint solution in Visual Studio to use this build server for automated builds. As starting point you can use these posts [here](http://matthiasbaumann.me/2013/03/10/setting-up-tfs-build-server-for-sharepoint-2013/) and [here](http://msftplayground.com/2013/10/tfs-and-sharepoint-builds-including-automatic-deployments-part-1/), and the CodePlex project [here](http://officesharepointci.codeplex.com/).

Comment: thanks for your reply,@pholpar.Currently i dont have a separate box for TFS, its configured in one of my dev environments.So should i  configure in this dev box itself ?

Comment: Having TFS on an dev. environment can technically work, but is not a best practice, as a dev. environment has typically much more assemblies installed on as a build server should have. It is hard to guarantee, that you can build your project later based on the artifacts / code in the repository, as referenced assemblies might be missing.